# What are the different durations for debuffs in Final Fantasy Record Keeper?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

I've noticed that different debuffs tend to expire at different times. Typically, some can wear off during battle, some at the end of a battle, and others last until you complete the entire encounter. What are the duration limits for the debuffs in FFRK?

Answer (score 1):

**Negative Effects:**

```
- Blind: 60 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 50 MND. reduce ACC by 50% then divide Hit Rate by 4  
- Sleep: 30 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 50 MND
- Confuse 30 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 40 MND
- Silence 20 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 40 MND
- Slow: 20 seconds, + 1 sec per 20k MND (not a typo)
- Paralyze: 15 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 50 MND
- Stop: 6 seconds, +/- 1 sec per 50 MND
- Poison: Infinite duration. MaxHP/64 damage every 5 seconds
- Power Break: 15 seconds, enemy physical damage reduced to 49%
- Magic Break: 15 seconds, enemy magical damage reduced to 51.7%
- Armor Break: 15 seconds, enemy physical damage taken increased to 119.5%
- Mental Break: 15 seconds, enemy mental damage taken increased to 119.5%
- Power Breakdown: 15? seconds, enemy physical damage reduced to 36%
- Magic Breakdown: 15? seconds, enemy magical damage reduced to 38.9%
- Armor Breakdown: 15? seconds, enemy physical damage taken increased to 129.1%
- Mental Breakdown: 15? seconds, enemy mental damage taken increased to 129.1%
```

**Positive Effects:**

```
- Regen: 35 seconds, + 1 sec per 33.3 MND. restore 3% MaxHP every 3 seconds
- Boost: 25 seconds
- Haste: 20 seconds, + 1 sec per 40 MND
- Retaliate: 15 seconds
- Protect: 35 seconds + 1 sec per 33.3 MND
- Shell: 35 seconds + 1 sec per 33.3 MND
- Reflect: 35 seconds + 1 sec per 33.3 MND
```

**Status that continue until the next Battle:**

```
- Death  
- Poison  
- Silence  
- Blind  
- Petrify
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/FFRecordKeeper/wiki/index/mechanics

Comment: Hmm, didn't realize blind had a fixed duration. I've never had it fall off before, and I'm sure I've been afflicted by it for more than 60 seconds. Do the durations reset in between battles?